# “A palla” (p.es.: “mettere la radio a palla”) - origine della locuzione

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Il vocabolario Treccani riporta, [alla sottoaccezione **2.n** di **palla¹**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/palla1/):

> pop. Locuz. *a palla*, al massimo, a tutta velocità: *sentire la musica a
>   p.*; *mettere la radio a p.*; *gli piace il brivido di andare a palla in
>   macchina!*; oppure *avere gli occhi a p.*, sgranati.

Non capisco perché l'espressione *avere gli occhi a palla* sia accomunata con le altre espressioni riportate, ma la domanda è: qual è l'origine della locuzione *a palla* nelle altre espressioni?

Posso ipotizzare che la locuzione *a palla* sia stata dapprima utilizzata nel senso di *alla velocità di un proiettile*, cioè *ad altissima velocità*, per poi passare al senso di *alla massima intensità*.

Personalmente la conoscevo, sin dagli anni '70, solo in quest'ultimo senso. Quindi non avrei mai detto *andare a palla in macchina*, mentre non mi suonerebbe strano se qualcuno mi dicesse di avere fatto un tratto di strada *con il gas a palla* (cioè *a tutto gas*). Curiosamente però mi suonerebbe meglio se il gas fosse stato dato tramite una manopola piuttosto che tramite un pedale.

Comment: Potrebbe riferirsi a qualche simbolo per esempio palla vuota, metà palla oppure palla piena e in questo caso si dice a palla cioe al massimo...

Comment: @eliosequino: La teoria mi piace, ma senza prove a supporto è un po' fiacca :/

Comment: @eliosequino: Trovo anch'io che sia una supposizione senza alcuna prova.

Answer (score 5):

L'espressione è diffusa in tutta l'Italia ed il significato è esattamente quello da te riportato, ossia "a tutta velocità" e (per estensione) "al massimo".
L'origine non è chiara, ma potrebbe derivare da un'espressione apparentemente presente solo al Sud, probabilmente nei pressi di Reggio Calabria: "[a tiro di palla](http://www.italysoft.com/curios/dizio-giovani/index.php)".
L'origine di quest'ultima è altrettanto incerta: "palla" potrebbe indicare un pallone o una palla di cannone; entrambi gli oggetti difatti si muovono a gran velocità. Da questo modo di dire, molto probabilmente, deriva l'estensione del concetto prima a tutto ciò che viaggia velocemente, poi a tutto ciò che è al massimo, a piena potenza.

Comment: La fonte è solo il "dizionario dei giovani" del link? Riporta come torinesi parole in siciliano, per dirne una... Anche sull'interpretazione di palla come pallone avrei da ridire. Fonte?

Comment: Purtroppo l'unica fonte che sono riuscito a trovare è quella. Che sia davvero un'espressione di RC non ho modo di confermarlo, di certo è un modo di dire esistente. Palla può o riferirsi a pallone, o a palla di cannone, altre interpretazioni sono improbabili. In ogni caso, il significato è analogo: ad alta velocità.

Comment: Nel nord si dice anche "a balla", il che potrebbe anche riferirsi a "ballare" o a "prendere una balla" (ubriacarsi).

Comment: Sostengo l'ipotesi della palla di cannone. In [questo volume](https://books.google.it/books?id=xkkZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA279&lpg=PA279&dq=%22a+palla%22+origine&source=bl&ots=rwqSkiKDop&sig=chH4Byc3AlnulIMBzM-B6lHS6s8&hl=it&sa=X&ei=EKqdVdn2BcmqU9emppgL&ved=0CFoQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22a%20palla%22%20origine&f=false) ho trovato l'espressione "colpo di cannone, tirato a palla contro la porta"